# Добавить сортировку при выборке из Бд - SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, order-by

Я не знаком с пайтоном и тем более с SQLAlchemy. Один паренек написал нам код и пропал, а нам надо добавить сортировку в запрос. В классе CRUD, вот в этот метод:

```
    @staticmethod
    def get_distinct_column(db_session: Session, column: str) -> List[dict]:
        # city,  partner_id, site
        ds = db_session.query(getattr(OrdersTable, column)).distinct().filter(getattr(OrdersTable, column) != '').all()
        return [u._asdict() for u in ds]
```

Я пытался сделать так:

```
ds = db_session.query(getattr(OrdersTable, column)).distinct().filter(getattr(OrdersTable, column) != '').order_by(f"{column}").all()
```

Не работает. Прошу помощи.
также есть такие фрагменты:

```
class OrdersTable(Base):
    """Model user"""
    __tablename__ = 'orders'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}
```

и вызов метода :

```
@app.get('/params/{column}', response_model=List[schemas.Parems], summary='Получение параметров', tags=["Analytic"])
async def get_params(column: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db), user=Depends(user_fastapi.current_user(active=True))):
    data_params = crud_orders.get_distinct_column(db, column)
    items = []
    for item in data_params:
        for key, value in item.items():
            items.append(schemas.Parems(key=key, value=value).dict())
    return [dict(s) for s in set(frozenset(d.items()) for d in items)]
```

УПД
сделал в методе get_distinct_column:

```
ds = db_session.query(getattr(OrdersTable, column)).distinct().filter(getattr(OrdersTable, column) != '').order_by(getattr(OrdersTable, column)).all()
```

работает, но порядка нет, хотя он и стал другим.
потом сделал в main.py в методе async def get_params:

```
return [dict(s) for s in (frozenset(d.items()) for d in items)]
```

убрал set
перестало работать совсем

Comment: Какая-то ошибка появилась или как выражается "перестало работать совсем"? Если ошибка - дайте текст ошибки.

Comment: я не умею логгировать ошибки в пайтоне. ориентируюсь по фронту и ответам из бэкенда. Выражается, что фронт после последнего исправления пишет - сервер не отвечает. Если можете помочь и Вам это интересно - предлагаю списаться в телеграм https://t.me/oko_elm

Comment: Бэк куда-то должен писать логи. Или выводить ошибки в stdout. Выложите полностью куда-нибудь что в итоге сейчас с функцией get_params и полностью код класса, где этот метод get_distinct_column

Comment: Если уж совсем ступор можно оставить как было и сортировать на фронте. А в это время найти бэкендера)

Answer (score 1):

order_by на вход принимает сами атрибуты класса, привязанные к колонкам таблицы. А вы пытаетесь передать строку с названием колонки. Для получения объекта самого атрибута используйте подход автора функции - `getattr(OrdersTable, column)`

```
ds = db_session.query(getattr(OrdersTable, column)).distinct().filter(getattr(OrdersTable, column) != '').order_by(getattr(OrdersTable, column)).all()
```

Для лучшей читаемости можно так

```
@staticmethod
def get_distinct_column(db_session: Session, column: str) -> List[dict]:
    # city,  partner_id, site
    selected_column = getattr(OrdersTable, column)
    ds = db_session.query(selected_column).distinct().filter(selected_column != '').order_by(selected_column).all()
    return [u._asdict() for u in ds]
```

Вы добавили ещё код. Там порядок и ломается. Не буду вникать в целесообразность всей конструкции, но для восстановления порядка попробуйте это

```
return [dict(s) for s in set(frozenset(d.items()) for d in items)]
```

Поменять на это

```
return [dict(s) for s in (frozenset(d.items()) for d in items)]
```

Comment: спасибо. попробовал. сортировка изменилась, но всё равно не по порядку.

Comment: @ElmElm
А какие там данные? Приведите пример в вопросе. Как выводится и как надо чтобы выводилось.

Comment: Этим методом последовательно выбираются три колонки из бд. в одной список доменов, в другой список городов, в третьей список организаций. Например города : в столбце в бд идут беспорядочно начинается с Санкт-Петербург, Смоленск, Екатеринбург .....
на выходе скрипта сейчас : Орск, Каспийск, Таганрог .....

Comment: Для лучшей читаемости - так вообще не работает.

Comment: @ElmElm Странно, потому что у меня работает. А порядок  у вас дальше ломается, так как сеты не соблюдают порядка данных. Там надо переписывать код. Честно говоря с ходу не понимаю зачем так усложнили.

Comment: отдается джейсон, где вся выборка разбивается на массивы по 100 элементов(не знаю тоже зачем - видимо фронт так понимает) - в них пара ключ-значение: [{key: "city", value: "Орск"}, {key: "city", value: "Каспийск"}, {key: "city", value: "Таганрог"},…]
[0 … 99]
[100 … 199]
[200 … 247]

Comment: @ElmElm Я дополнил ответ. Попробуйте в строке вместо сета использовать генератор. Для этого просто надо стереть слово set. Но могут появиться повторы записей. Возможно set там был для того, чтобы оставить только уникальные значения.

Comment: попробовал - вообще не работает так.

Comment: @ElmElm Покажите как вы сделали в вопросе или со ссылкой на кодообменник.

Answer (score 1):

вобщем ларчик просто открывался:
заменил `return` в async `def get_params`
вместо

```py
return [dict(s) for s in (frozenset(d.items()) for d in items)]
```

просто

```py
return items
```

и - о, чудо, всё стало как надо.

Спасибо огромное господину Alpensin, за то, что вдохновил на поиски решения.